# hhc Windows help file does not process quotes or double quotes well

Tags: html, windows, chm, double-quotes, quote

I noticed that when compiling a chm file, if the tree contains any articles that have a double quote in its title such as *How to use the "?" correctly*, it won't process the tree properly.  In the actual help file, the title would actually read *How to use the*.

Is there a problem with Windows Help Files, in its ability to process quotes?  Or, do I have to specify character encoding somewhere to get around this issue?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Afaik topic titles are wchars in the index, and the rest is simply html. So probably a limitation of the CHM compiler and not of the format.

Unfortunately, there is not much that you can do about that.

OTOH html afaik requires " to be replaced by  & quot; did you try that ?

P.s. the ampersand and quote must touch of course, but the forum software would then turn it into a "